# Initializing a new highcharts object over old

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am getting the following error when calling `chart.loadData` in the javascript below

> TypeError: c.style is undefined. highcharts.src.js:18788:15

---

**Edit: Solved (kinda)**

The cause for this particular error was due to attempting to define a `v.__prototype__.constructor` in a completely different js file upstream (with no naming conflicts to anything in the HighCharts code). Of course, that makes no sense, but that's javascript for you

---

**Rest of Original Post**

where I have Highcharts JS v6.1.4 (2018-09-25) and that line within the `addTitle` function (when unminified?) is `if (!axisTitleOptions.style.width && !axis.isRadial)`

I have the following js code

```
var chart = {
    id: 'tr_chart',
    chart_obj: null,
    $elem: null,
    nodata: null,
    options: {},
    defaultOptions: function() {
        this.options = new Object({
            chart: { type: 'line'
        }, title: {
            text: 'Distance away'
        }, xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime', title: {
                text: "Date"
            },
            min: null, max: null
        }, yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'km'
            },
        }, series: [] })
    },
    startinit: function() {
        // set up chart
        this.defaultOptions();
        this.options.xAxis.min = parameters.startDate.valueOf(); //yes, these really do have values
        this.options.xAxis.max = parameters.endDate.valueOf();
    init: function(){
        this.startinit();
        this.chart_obj = Highcharts.chart(this.id, this.options);
        this.$elem = $(".tr_chart");
    },
    loadData: function(data){
        if (data.length < 1) {
            // this.restoreNoData();
            return;
        }
        this.startinit();
        console.log(this.options);
        // more code is here and ends with...
        this.chart_obj = Highcharts.chart(this.id, this.options);
    }
}
```

The following HTML code exists in the encapsulating page (in addition to jQuery, etc.)

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
...
<div id="tr_chart">
</div>
```

There is only the indicated single object (div or otherwise) that has that id value.

In loadData at the logging line, according to Firefox's inspector console, somehow my this.options object is not re-initialized to the default options.  Instead the series is filled in with data points, and has several additional properties. Specifically, it has values for `chart.options.xAxis.index`, `chart.options.xAxis.isX`, `chart.options.series[i]._colorIndex` and `chart.options.series[i]._symbolIndex`, suggesting that the options object is still populated with metadata and data from an earlier call to the `Highcharts.chart` "constructor."

The data-truncated `options` object is (after attempting re-initialization):

```
{
  "chart": {
    "type": "line"
  },
  "title": {
    "text": "Distance away"
  },
  "xAxis": {
    "type": "datetime",
    "title": {
      "text": "Date"
    },
    "min": 1262332800000,
    "max": 1538681082811,
    "index": 0,
    "isX": true
  },
  "yAxis": {
    "title": {
      "text": "km"
    },
    "index": 0
  },
  "series": [
    {
      "name": "my first series name",
      "data": [
        [
          1422619771000,
          188.964
        ],
        [
          1422620874000,
          188.964
        ],
        [
          1423058407000,
          106.54
        ],
        [
          1423104758000,
          106.54
        ]
      ],
      "_colorIndex": 0,
      "_symbolIndex": 0
    },
    {
      "name": "and the second series name here",
      "data": [
        [
          1263477629000,
          325.329
        ],
        [
          1263477725000,
          325.329
        ],
        [
          1263519764000,
          287.487
        ],
        [
          1263519764000,
          287.487
        ] // ... and 100 more data points in this second series
     ],
      "_colorIndex": 1,
      "_symbolIndex": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Am I missing something in the handling of objects in javascript?  Is highcharts hooking into the "options" object with the first call to the constructor and not allowing me to replace the object?

---

I believe this may be connected...I'm receiving the following warnings/non-fatal errors in highcharts

```
Error in parsing value for ‘text-anchor’.  Declaration dropped. 
Unexpected value NaN parsing x attribute. highcharts.src.js:7324:18
Unexpected value undefined parsing rx attribute. highcharts.src.js:1119:14
Unexpected value undefined parsing ry attribute. highcharts.src.js:1119:14
Unexpected value NaN parsing x attribute. highcharts.src.js:5283:10
Unexpected value NaN parsing y attribute. highcharts.src.js:5283:10
Unexpected value NaN parsing width attribute. highcharts.src.js:5283:10
Unexpected value NaN parsing height attribute. highcharts.src.js:5283:10
Unexpected value NaN parsing width attribute. highcharts.src.js:5283:10
Unexpected value NaN parsing height attribute.
```

I also notice that there's an `elem.styles` and an `elem.element.style`, but not an `elem.style`. where `elem.element` is an object of type `text.highcharts-title`  here is a stack trace of that approximate location.

```
fontMetrics (highcharts.src.js#7352)
layOutTitles (highcharts.src.js#26291)
each (highcharts.src.js#2270)
layOutTitles (highcharts.src.js#26279)
setTitle (highcharts.src.js#26259)
render (highcharts.src.js#27293)
firstRender (highcharts.src.js#27588)
init (highcharts.src.js#25734)
fireEvent (highcharts.src.js#2533)
init (highcharts.src.js#25607)
getArgs (highcharts.src.js#25578)
Chart (highcharts.src.js#25498)
chart (highcharts.src.js#25547)
init (fishtrack4_OSM.js#782)
(anonymous) (fishtrack4_OSM.js#912)
j (jquery.js#2)
fireWith (jquery.js#2)
ready (jquery.js#2)
J (jquery.js#2)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is too broad and it would be great too see the working example, because I'm not able to reproduce your issue basing on provided code (syntax errors, no sample data and way of usage whole `chart` object), so could you try to reproduce the issue using some live coding platform (e.g JSFiddle)?

Comment: Here is the example based on your code, but with a few fixes. Everything is fine. https://jsfiddle.net/qo2ukx18/

Comment: On my site I'm getting a lot of `width="NaN"` and other `NaN` and `0` values where a page that is working has a lot of actual values in the inserted data-highcharts-chart inner divs.  I'm at a loss to see if my page code is somehow overwriting a variable inside highcharts.

Comment: So, could you produce some live demo which shows the problem? It's hard to guess what exactly cause that type of the problem.

Comment: It's definitely some kind of problem with your application implementation, not Highcharts, because, every generating of Highcharts chart ends with some errors, even if it's simple configuration type. If I tried to build the chart with the same configuration, but in pure JSFiddle example, everything works well.

Comment: yep...i don't understand it;)

Comment: Heh, looks like my server is running jQuery 1.11.3.  That's...um...old.  And upgrading is likely to break 150 other things.  Well, time to plunge into the rabbit hole.

Comment: the cause for this particular error was due to attempting to define a `v.__prototype__.constructor` in a completely different js file upstream with no naming conflicts to anything in the HighCharts code.  Of course, that makes no sense, but that's javascript for you.